# How to return the result of this outside of the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the `result` returned where I call the function. How can I do this?
I get the result through the `console.log(result)` but not the `console.log(finger)`.

I want to pass it outside.

```
function fingercode() {
    var fp = new Fingerprint2();
    fp.get(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    });
}

var finger = fingercode();
console.log(finger);
```

Comment: what does `fp.get` actually do? You can't return a deffered function because it's execution is deffered . You'll need some kind of callback

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `fp.get` does some form of ajax get/load?  If so, just search SO for the 100s of duplicate questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: or [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `callback` function

```
function fingercode(callback) {
      var fp = new Fingerprint2();
      fp.get(callback);
}

fingercode(function(finger){
    console.log(finger);
});
```

Comment: `fp.get(callback);` would do the same thing and easier to read

Comment: I get this Uncaught ReferenceError: finger is not defined

Comment: @villoui are you sure that you copied exatcly that, with `finger` being a parameter of the anonymous function passed to `fingercode`?

Comment: Do you have any other code (excluding answer code)?